# Is there any way to run a python script on remote machine without sending it?

Tags: python, ssh

I can run a shell script on remote machine with ssh. For example:

```
ssh -l foo 192.168.0.1 "`cat my_script.sh`"
```

Now I want to run a python script without sending .py file. Is there any way?

Comment: You are obviously sending the script to be run. Do you mean "without copying a file to the remote machine"?

Comment: Yes, I mean without copying a file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will put the contents of my_script.py on your computer into an echo command that is performed on the remote computer and passed into python.

```
ssh -l foo 192.168.0.1 "echo '`cat my_script.py`' | python"
```

If you want to add command line args it should be as simple as putting them after the python command like so:

```
ssh -l foo 192.168.0.1 "echo '`cat my_script.py`' | python -testSwitch -arg 0"
```

Make sure that the command line args are inside the double quotes of the command you are sending to the remote host.

Comment: This works after delete double quotes of cat command. So right answer will be this: ssh -l foo 192.168.0.1 "echo '`cat my_script.py`' | python"

Comment: I have another point! How can I give command line argument to this python script?

Comment: That should be easy, just put the args after the python command, I'll edit the answer to show you an example.

Comment: I can't get the example with the args to work. It seems like you can't pass arguments to a python interactive session...